# Need to pull data from October using MONTH(TODAY())

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

I need to pull data from October, and not for the current month.

I've tried to replace "TODAY" with October, but it isn't working.

Below is the formula used

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), MONTH(TODAY()), JIRA!D:D, "completed")&" / "& COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), MONTH(TODAY()), JIRA!D:D, "scheduled"))
```

Comment: I think I figured it out with

=ARRAYFORMULA( COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), MONTH(NOW())-1, JIRA!D:D, "completed")&" / "& COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), MONTH(NOW())-1, JIRA!D:D, "scheduled"))

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), MONTH("October"&1), JIRA!D:D, "completed")&" / "& 
 COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), MONTH("October"&1), JIRA!D:D, "scheduled"))
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), MONTH("Oct"&1), JIRA!D:D, "completed")&" / "& 
 COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), MONTH("Oct"&1), JIRA!D:D, "scheduled"))
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), MONTH("10/10/2019"), JIRA!D:D, "completed")&" / "& 
 COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), MONTH("10/10/2019"), JIRA!D:D, "scheduled"))
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), 10, JIRA!D:D, "completed")&" / "& 
 COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, E2, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), 10, JIRA!D:D, "scheduled"))
```